# Is it possible to debug Javascript running in an iFrame in IE9

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, debugging

I have a facebook app using a lot of Javascript that doesn't work correctly in IE (8 and 9), so I'd like to use a debugger. Unfortunately, the IE JS debugger doesn't allow you to choose Javascript files running in an iFrame, and I can't run it directly since then the facebook autorization doesn't work.

Is there a way to get the IE developer tools to recognize Javascript running inside an iFrame?

Comment: have tried writing debugg; in you script..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you are debugging under the script tab, then search for the function you want to set a breakpoint on. It should highlight/find the script file.

I use IE Developer Tools to debug a IFrame based application on a regular basis.

Do the scripts from other domains show up in the source explorer (beside the debugging button) under the script tab?

Edit:

Using a this simple test I confirmed IE Developer Tools will load scripts on external domains:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://msdn.com" height="400" width="400" />
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I search for a function? The scripts don't show up in the dropdown box, that's exactly the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt have you clicked Start Debugging under the scripts tab? The scripts don't show up until this button is clicked. Then you can search for "function myFunc" etc. from the search box in the upper right hand corner.

Comment: You're right, they show up once the button is clicked, how unintuitive. Thanks, that solves my problem!

Comment: Actually, debugging javascript on IE 10 is problematic. You find the javascript of Iframe, and you can register a break point on it. However, if the point where you wish to set a break point is a function called during onload and the way the page is geting loaded is through e.g. a GET request. WHen the new page page is reported back to the browser, the breakpoint set on the javascript file before the GET request is useless. You cannot debug it in IE. And of course, none of this is an issue in Chrome and Firefox... as usual.